# after i added scroll: tag there no anything display in kivy python

Tags: python, kivy

here is my kv file. in there has added a scroll tag for scroll view when I write after something stac code they have not to work.[Here my image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRxGM.png).

1st I have used stac: in this case, it was worked. but after I added scroll: and not display anything after I added down of scroll.i tried same way in youtube but my one didn't worked [here images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugPyL.png)

```
Scroll:

<Scroll@ScrollView>:
    stac:



<stac>:
    size_hint:1,None
    height:400
    #left-right top-bottom
    #horizontal
    #orientation:"lr-bt"
    #padding:("200dp","200dp","100dp","200dp")
    #spacing:"20dp","20dp"




<grid@GridLayout>:

#rows
#columns
    rows:2
    Button:
        text: "A"
        size_hint:None,.1
        width:"60dp"
    Button:
        text: "b"
    boxlay:
        text: "c"

    Button:
        text: "d"
        #size_hint:.5,.9
    Button:
        text: "e"
    Button:
        text: "f"

<anc>:
#right,left,center
#bottom,top,center
    anchor_x:"right"
    anchor_y:"bottom"
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint:.2,.2
        Button:
            text: "A"
            #size_hint:.2,.2
            #x,center_x,right
            #y,center_y,top
            pos_hint:{"right":.8}
            spacing:"10dp"

        Button:
            text: "B"
           # size_hint:.2,.2
            #x,center_x,right
            #y,center_y,top
            pos_hint:{"right":.3}
            spacing:"10dp"


<boxlay>:
    #horizontal
    #orientation:'vertical'
    Button:
        text: "A"
        size_hint:.2,.2
        #x,center_x,right
        #y,center_y,top
        pos_hint:{"right":.8}
        spacing:"10dp"
    Button:
        text: "A"



<main_widget>:
    Button:
        text:"hello"
        size:"100dp","80dp"
        pos:"100dp","200dp"
        color:1,1,0,1

    Label:
        text:"hello"
        size:"100dp","80dp"
        pos:"300dp","200dp"
        color:1,0,0,1
```

here this is my python file

```
 from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.metrics import dp
    from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
    from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
    from kivy.uix.button import Button
    from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
    #from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
    from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
    from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
    
    
    
    class stac(StackLayout):
    
    
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    
            super().__init__(**kwargs)
            ##self.orientation="lr-bt"
    
            for i in range(0, 100):
                size = dp(100)
                b1 = Button(text=str(i + 1), size_hint=(None, None), size=(dp(size), dp(size)))
                self.add_widget(b1)
    
    
    
    
    """class grid(GridLayout):
        pass"""
    
    
    class anc(AnchorLayout):
        pass
    
    
    class boxlay(BoxLayout):
        pass
        """
    


    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        ##self.orientation='vertical'
        b1=Button(text="A",)
        b2 = Button(text="B")
        b3 = Button(text="c")
        self.add_widget(b1)
        self.add_widget(b2)
        self.add_widget(b3)

"""


class main_widget(Widget):
    pass


class myapp(App):
    pass


myapp().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

Well hidden in the [documentation for kivy language](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html) is:

> Keep class names capitalized to avoid syntax errors.

I believe your code will work if you just capitalize all your class names.